# drop_table migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im having problems deleting a table that i created in migration.

executing `rake db:migration VERSION=0` appears to be successful but looking at mysql the table is still present and `schema.rb` data is not removed.

```
def up
create_table :subjects do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "position"
    t.boolean "visible", :default => false
    t.timestamps 
end
def down
    drop_table :subjects
end
```

*Typo Edited: subject -> subjects*

this happens only when i use `def down`. `def change` gives me no problem and deletes the table.

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite it this way:

```
def up
  drop_table :subjects
end

def down
  create_table :subjects do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "position"
    t.boolean "visible", :default => false
    t.timestamps 
  end
end
```

Take note of how **:subjects** is used as opposed to **:subject**.

After this, you should now run rake `db:migrate`. To recover table, run `rake db:rollback`. The `up` method should describe the **migration** and `down` method the **rollback**

Comment: i tried using `def change` and it works smoothly. not sure why `def up/down` doesnt produce the same result deleting my `:subjects` table. its really bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

Your migration is fine, but it needs to be `drop_table :subjects` not `drop_table :subject`

Comment: thanks for pointing out my typo.  upon editing `:subjects` i still get the same result. i can rollback to my `VERSION=0` successfully but  table`subjects` still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxx
```

where `xxx` is version of your migration file. For example, if your migration file name is `20160710042640_create_subjects.rb` then run `db:migrate:down VERSION=20160710042640`

Comment: i can see the status as `down` when i executed your code and no error showed. but checking the mysql, the table is still there.